# how to get duplicates when I group rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table:

- MyTable(ID, FK, ...)

I am using this query:

```
select ID fromMytable were FK <> 1
group by ID, FK
order by ID
```

This gives me the result that I want:

- 255
- 255
- 267
- 268
- 790
- ...

The 255 is duplicate because has two differnt KFs. The rest of the IDs has the same FK. I would like to get the IDs which has more than one FK and has differents values.

If an ID has two rows with FK = 2 and FK = 3 then get this ID, but if the ID has FK = 2, FK = 2, FK = 2 I don't want this ID because it has the same FK.

How could I get this IDs?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should count distinct `FK`s

```
select ID from Mytable where FK <> 1
group by ID
having count(distinct FK) > 1
order by ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the key was the having count distinct of the FK.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` to find only ID that exists more one once:

```
select DISTINCT ID
from Mytable
where FK <> 1
group by ID, FK
having count(*) >= 2
order by ID
```

Comment: I dont think you require `DISTINCT ID`...simple `ID` would do the job. :)

Comment: If I remove DISTINCT, dupliced FK's will be listed several times. (I do group by id AND fk.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    fromMytable 
WHERE 
     FK <> 1
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT ID FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN, ID 
    from Mytable WHERE FK <> 1
) TMP
WHERE RN = 1
```